# How can I access a list of functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, graphics3d

I found answers to this question but I don't know how to apply them to the code below. 
The code below rotates a cube with edges of length 1 by an angle p around the z axis. The origin of the coordinate axis is in the center of the cube.
B is a list of eight points with each point containing three coordinates (x,y,z) and each coordinate can be a function of the angle p. I would like to change the angle p in the `Animate` command. But in my code I first have to replace `p` by `a` which I think is not the right way to do it.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(* Rotation Matrix about z *)
aZ = {
  {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0},
  {-Sin[p], Cos[p], 0},
  {0, 0, 1}};
(* Cube *)
V = {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}; (* Offset *)
(* Corners *)
{ A0 = {0, 0, 0} - V,
  B0 = {1, 0, 0} - V,
  C0 = {1, 1, 0} - V,
  D0 = {0, 1, 0} - V,
  A1 = {0, 0, 1} - V,
  B1 = {1, 0, 1} - V,
  C1 = {1, 1, 1} - V,
  D1 = {0, 1, 1} - V};
A = {A0, B0, C0, D0, A1, B1, C1, D1};
(* Edges *)
grA = Line[{
    {A0, B0, C0, D0, A0},
    {A1, B1, C1, D1, A1},
    {A0, A1}, {B0, B1}, {C0, C1}, {D0, D1}
    }];
(* Rotated Corners by angel p *)
B = A; (* initialising B *)
(* List of functions: How can they be accessed: B[[i]][p_]:= ? *)
Table[B[[i]] = aZ . A[[i]], {i, 1, 8}]
Out = {{-(Cos[p]/2) - Sin[p]/2, -(Cos[p]/2) + Sin[p]/2, -(1/2)}, 
       {  Cos[p]/2  - Sin[p]/2, -(Cos[p]/2) - Sin[p]/2, -(1/2)}, ...}
(* Edges of rotated cube like grA *)
grB = Line[{
    {B[[1]], B[[2]], B[[3]], B[[4]], B[[1]]},
    {B[[5]], B[[6]], B[[7]], B[[8]], B[[5]]},
    {B[[1]], B[[5]]}, {B[[2]], B[[6]]}, {B[[3]], B[[7]]}, {B[[4]], 
     B[[8]]}
    }];
(* This doesn't work 
Animate[Graphics3D[{{Blue,grB},{Red,grA}},PlotRange\[Rule]{{-1,1},{-1,\
1},{-1,1}}],{p,0,\[Pi]/2},AnimationRunning\[Rule]False]
*)
Animate[Graphics3D[{{Blue, grB /. p -> a}, {Red, grA}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {a, 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: Are you aware that `RotationMatrix[]` is built-in?

Comment: Thank you. So far as I can see this replaces ``aZ`` but I think that this doesn't answers my question or have I something overseen?

Comment: Sorry. This question can be deleted. f[x_]:= {{x,x^2},{Sin[x],Cos[x]}}; f[x][[2,1]] yields Sin[x].